# C++ FLTK 1.30 MSVCR120.dll Missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, release, fltk

My current problem, with the C++ FLTK library (v 1.30), is that I have never been able to create a Release Build that properly works on other PC's.

While reading through "Programming Principles and Practice using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup, I've started really enjoying using FLTK, only to realize that I can't use my programs on other PC's without installing DLL's or Run-times.

All the code runs and compiles just fine, but when I try putting it on another PC it pops up with the error "MSVCR120.dll missing" or something along those lines.

My IDE is Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional and my FLTK version is 1.30.

My project properties are as follows:

> Additional Dependencies: 
>   fltk.lib
>   wsock32.lib
>   comctl32.lib
>   fltkjpeg.lib
>   fltkimages.lib

(Apparently, for debug mode it's meant to be fltkd.lib, fltkjpegd.lib, etc)

```
      > Ignore Specific Default Libraries:
```

libcd.lib
LIBCMT.lib (I added LIBCMT, so that when compiling in /MT it wouldn't produce errors, could be a bad idea but the program still compiles and runs with no errors unless I try run it on another PC)

```
      > Runtime Library: Multi-threaded (/MT)
```

I am compiling in "Release".

I followed every single instruction in the Appendix for the book which explains how to install FLTK, except I used a different version (FLTK 1.1.9 doesn't seem to compile) and I built and ran FLTK.sln instead of .dsw.

When I created the project in VS2013, I chose empty project. No configuration properties were changed besides the ones I mentioned.

Comment: Have you built FLTK as /MT?  Try building FLTK as /MT then link it with your program, also built as /MT.  Remove the "ignored" files - it tells you if something is amiss.  If all is OK, there should not be any errors or warnings.  If there are errors, fix them instead of using ignore.

Comment: I did exactly as you asked, and the FLTK test example compiled and ran on another PC! However, I have noticed that adding Mr. Stroustrups headers to any project results in it not being able to compile unless I build in Debug Mode. I will try to get Mr. Stroustrups Headers to work, if that does not work, I'll just remove them. Thank you so much!

Comment: Have a look at the include directories.  They should be the same on both Debug and Release.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the problems are in the headers. Every single time I try to even #include "Simple_window.h" for example, it produces errors saying that _free, and _malloc are already defined in LIBCMT.lib. It also produces errors saying "error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(typinfo.obj)"

Answer (score 1):

Install the  [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) on the other 
PCs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually considered this, and I will probably resort to this if there is no alternative. However, I want my program to be  as portable as possible. For example, with this fix, if I end up on a work PC that doesn't have access to the internet, there's no way I can get my program to work.

Comment: Install files found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC120.CRT" in the same directory as your application.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, this is a really good idea. Still, I would be very pleased to here of a way to make my program completely standalone. Thanks.

Comment: link statically to the CRT